# How to append a div inside an appended div

Tags: javascript, html, append

```
    $.each(v.Modifiers, function (_k, _v) {
      $modifierDiv.append(
        `<div class="col-xs-12 cart-modifier" style="padding: 0;" data-id="${_v.ModifierOptionID}">
          <p class="text-muted" style="padding: 5px; margin: 0; line-height: 14px;">
            ${_v.ModifierOption.Name + " " + formatCurrency(_v.TotalPrice)}
          </p>
        </div>`
      );
    });

    $(".cart-items-right").find('ul').append(
      `<div class="row">
        <li class="col-xs-12 receipt-item" data-order-line-id="${obj.OrderLineID}" data-id="${obj.ID}" data-qty="${obj.Qty}" data-remarks="${obj.Remarks}" data='${JSON.stringify(obj)}'>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-9" style="padding: 0;">
                <span class="col-xs-8 text-muted" style="padding:5px 0px;margin:0px;line-height:14px;">
                  ${common.translate("Regular") + " " +formatCurrency(obj.Price)}
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 hidden" style="margin: 8px 0;">${$modifierDiv}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>`
    );
```

I appended $modifierDiv inside a div that also append to .cart-items-right. But it just returned me [Object Object]. Need help. Thanks

Comment: Appending a `<div>`  to a `<ul>` is invalid markup. Only child allowed for the `<ul>` is `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a jQuery object for the `<li>` then append within that object

Simplified example:

```js
const $div = $('<div>',{text:'My Div'})

const $li = $(`<li><div class="hidden"></div></li>`);
               
$li.find('.hidden').append($div)

$('ul').append($li)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```